# Connect to remote mysql server from localhost docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony

I have doctrine config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:pdo_mysql
        url:"mysql://%database_user%:%database_password%@%database_host%:%database_port%/%database_name%"
```

Where database_user is root, password is root user password (re-checked), host is my server ip address, port is 3306 and name is my db name.

When I use these from workbench I can connect but from running docker container for php and nginx. And this config, I get connection refused.

Do I need somehow to allow connections from localhost? Why is it working from workbench then?

Comment: Have you looked at docker networks? this may be of help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69285724/mongo-db-connection-exception-from-another-container-in-docker/69301636#69301636

Comment: Isn't this if I want to run docker on host or access docker from host? I need to access remote host from local docker..